# Abort ongoing Jenkins build when the Pull Request in BitBucket is updated

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request

Here's my environment -
Jenkins V2.111 with Bitbucket Branch Source plugin V2.2.0
BitBucket V5.7.0

I have got the Multi Branch Pipeline Jenkins job working fine. The builds are triggered automatically - for a new branch created, new Pull Request created, updates on branches and updates on Pull Requests. However, I want the ongoing Jenkins builds to automatically abort when there is an update to the Pull Request. How do I achieve this?

Regards,
Anantha

Comment: Any update on this?